# How to display varbinary image to html table using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, model-view-controller

I am trying to display a `varbinary` image from a SQL table to html table data using jQuery and web service. Please help me how to convert int and how to display it.

My code is like this:

Web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public a[] Bindpics()
{
    DataTable dt = ga.retrievedata("select Picture from T_Sam");

    List<a> details = new List<a>();

    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        a m = new a();
        m.Pic = (byte[])dtrow["Picture"];
        details.Add(m);
    }

    return details.ToArray();
}

public class a
{
   public byte[] Pic { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery:

```
success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>"
                + "<img src=" + "'" + data.d[i].Pic + "'" + " />" + "</td></tr>");
        }
```

I am getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type \u0027System.DBNull\u0027 to type \u0027System.Byte[]\u0027

It is not displaying the image.

Please help me to convert it.

Comment: Do a check for dbnull before assigning it to property. also in the jquery, unless the pic is a url then you would need to use [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: It does not seem belong to an ASP.NET MVC project since there is WebMethod attribute in your code. Are you sure this is from an ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: @Nkosi ... Yes you are correct data is null i added data to all rows and i removed Data URI scheme also ... But now the service is executing without error but image is not displaying .....

Comment: @Nkosi I got the solution finally i coverted the image from webservice ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I converted the image from web service then the problem is solved ...

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.